# How do I prevent vscode from creating workspace files such as ".vscode/settings.json"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I open a new folder to edit some code (`code .`), opening the settings dialog (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) immediately creates a directory `.vscode` with a mostly empty file `settings.json`.

Since there are no workspace-specific settings, the file looks like:

```
{
}
```

For the time being, I do not want to have `.vscode` directories spread across my filesystem. I am happy with global settings.

Is there a way to disable this behavior and prevent Visual Studio Code from creating these files automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this isn't an option, but it is an open issue (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29251)). This post also contains some work-arounds for git projects.